# Change element of a map that's key is not in set B

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, set

I'm sure this comes up often enough for it to be addressed somewhere, but I wasn't sure how to search for it any further.

I want to modify the values from map that's key is not in set B.  What is the best method?  Here's what I had in mind:

```
Map<X,Y> map = ...

Set<X> B = ...

for(Map.Entry<X, Y> entry : map.entrySet() ) {

    if( ! B.contains(entry.getKey()) {
        entry.setValue( someMethod(entry.getValue);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have currently should work fine. As an alternative, you could try something like this:

```
Map<X,Y> newMap = new HashMap<X,Y>(map);
newMap.keySet().removeAll(B);  // remove keys in the set B

for (Map.Entry<X, Y> entry : newMap.entrySet()) {
    entry.setValue(someMethod(entry.getValue());
}

map.putAll(newMap);
```

Although I have to say, if I was doing this, I'd take your current approach.